# PHP loadHTMLFile(table.html) errors

Tags: php, domdocument

This is my script to load data from an old table which is to say it one way "un-editable".

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document -> loadHTMLFile('http://www.table.html');
$rows   = $document -> getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

After that I load the `<td>`'s into an array:

```
    $numRow = 0;
    foreach($rows as $result){

// 15 columns to load.
        for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
        $array[$numRow][$i] = $result
        ->getElementsByTagName('td')
        ->item($i)
        ->nodeValue;
        }
    $numRow++;
    }
```

So far all went fine, but then the problems started. All the rows have a string column for "description" and in the description there's frequently human mistype errors like for example:

this is a cell: `<td>Suppor<</td>` (somebody mistiped here IDK how) error: `Tag o invalid`

Or when cells contain "&" like this one:

Another example: `<td>From A&A Limited.</td>` error:  `htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'`

Errors always reffer to this line `$document -> loadHTMLFile('http://www.table.html');`

As you can see the table has `15 columns` being `$i = 4` the string column. I'm not a really PRO programmer and didn't really see this coming. Thanks in advance to any person that can give me a hand.

Comment: You should encode your & to &amp; if I recall correctly. I had something like that in the past and that's how I solved that (I think).  Solving wrongly formatted html in your input won't be so easy.

Comment: Sadly I can't do anything to filter the input.

Comment: That's too bad.  Also the encoding of & to &amp; was not what I did, I replaced it by ' and '.  Bad suggestion of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution doing this:

```
@$document -> loadHTMLFile('http://www.table.html');
$rows   = $document -> getElementsByTagName('tr');

$nodeListLength = htmlentities($rows->length);
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeListLength; $i ++)
{
    $node = $gastos->item(0);
    //-> VALORES A MOSTRAR EN TU QUERY
}
```

I hope it can help another person with the same problem.
Thanks to the people that check my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find any magical way to fix broken HTML, but you can change the way that libxml (which powers DOMDocument) handles errors slightly so that it gives you as much usable output as possible.  Have you tried changing the error handling to internal?  Check out [libxml_use_internal_errors()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before `$document->loadHTMLFile(...);`